Openldap and ruby dont work with ruby command
Hi iam new in openldap and i have a problem know for 5 days iam searching for the fails but i cant find anything.
Command is this here
ruby publish.rb dev app100 password app101-x-requests

its running in a Docker Container
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from app102.rb:1:in `<main>'
        2: from app101.rb:1:in `<main>'
        1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': : cannot load such file -- bunnycannot load such file -- bunny ( (LoadErrorLoadError)
)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from app100.rb:1:in `<main>'
        1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bunny (LoadError)


imho it Loks for "bunny"
